# How to sort `values` list passed to "autocomplete" editor?

Tags: tabulator

We can pass object to `values` editorParams of [`autocomplete`](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit#edit-builtin) editor:

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{
    values:{
        "steve":"Steve Boberson",
        "bob":"Bob Jimmerson",
        "jim":"Jim Stevenson",
    },
    showListOnEmpty : true,
}}
```

I want those values to be displayed in order when there is empty filter.

How to sort values from this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order they are defined in the object should be the order they are displayed on the screen,

you could also pass in the values list formatted as an array and set the order of the elements that way:

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{
    values:[
        {
            label:"Steve Boberson",
            value:"steve",
        },
        {
            label:"Bob Jimmerson",
            value:"bob",
        },
        {
            label:"Jim Stevenson",
            value:"jim",
        },
    ],
    showListOnEmpty : true,
}}
```